# Run recorded macro script when specific cell changes

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-tables, listobject

I am trying to have a recorded macro function based on a cell change.

The script for my recorded macro below automatically filters a table to only include values between 1 & 5 when you press run.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    // Clear filter on table table1 column "numbers"
    table1.getColumnByName("numbers").getFilter().clear();
    // Apply custom filter on table table1 column "numbers"
    table1.getColumnByName("numbers").getFilter().applyCustomFilter(">=0", "<=5", ExcelScript.FilterOperator.and);
}
```

The code I have for a cell change is below

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = Range("K1").Address Then

MsgBox "cell has changed"

End If

End Sub
```

I was hoping I could just copy and paste the redorded script into the if function. Apparently it doesn't work that way...

I'm very new to this stuff and just started learning today.

Comment: Well those are 2 different languages. You will need to understand what the original one does and reconstruct it in the new language.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know that it's two different languages... Though, since they're both in the same workbook, is there a way I can tell the VBA one (in the second script) to just run the script? Both function individually when tested.

Answer (score 1):

### A Workbook Sheet Change: Filter an Excel Table

- The following will filter table `Table1`, located in the workbook containing this code, on each change in cell `K1` of any of the worksheets.
- The code needs to be copied to the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Sh.Range("K1").Address Then
        With Range("Table1").ListObject
            If .ShowAutoFilter Then
                If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End If
            .Range.AutoFilter .ListColumns("Numbers").Index, ">=0", xlAnd, "<=5"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K1")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("Table1")
        Dim filterRange As Range
        Set filterRange = tbl.ListColumns("numbers").Range
        filterRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=5"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
End Sub
```